# Video recording using Intent saves empty file

Tags: android, android-intent, mediastore

This is the code i used to record video from an android device in MP4 format. The file is being created but is of 0 bytes size.
Here is my code :-

```
Button buttonStart;
File newFile;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initUI();
    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                newFile = File.createTempFile("vid", ".mp4", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newFile);
            Intent record = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            record.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(record, 5);
        }
    });
}

protected void initUI(){
    buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRecord);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 5){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            try {
                newFile = File.createTempFile("vid", ".mp4", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, "Video Captured Successfully...!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand what has gone wrong.
Can anybody help me ...
Thanks

Comment: why r u set temp file in video .......mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
            "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String strVideoPath=null;`//define global variable

to open an Intetn for video recording

```
void displayCamera() {
        File imagesFolder = new File(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory(), getResources()
                .getString(R.string.app_name) + "foldername");
        try {
            imagesFolder.mkdirs();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        File f_image = new File(imagesFolder, new Date().getTime() + ".mp4");
        Uri uriSavedVideo = Uri.fromFile(f_image);
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedVideo);
        strVideoPath = f_image.getAbsolutePath();

        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, 111);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

catch it on `OnActivity Result`

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 111) {
            if (resultCode == mActivity.RESULT_OK) {
                //do stuff here on success
            }else{
                strVideoPath=null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first u need to create a directory

```
     File newFileLocation;
     try {
        newFileLocation = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "videoyo");

                imagesFolder.mkdirs();
        newFile = new File(newFileLocation , "vid" + ".mp4");
            } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```